# Aggregate timeseries per minute data to hourly on large csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, aggregate

Hello I have a question about how to aggregate per minute data to an hourly level for each road segment.
The data should be grouped by hour and the road segment ID. Would this be possible to do on 15gb+ csv as I have only filtered only the relevant road segments to reduce the size to 1-2GB?

The data set is something like this

```
             DateTime              SegmentID    Speed
    2019-10-08T01:00:00+01:00          1          39
    2019-10-08T01:00:01+01:00          1          39
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resample()` pandas function. Then it looks like you'd want to get the sum() or mean() of the other columns?

```
df.resample('H').mean()
```

If your `DateTime` column is not your index you will have to do:

```
df.resample('H', on='DateTime').mean()
```

You can use other aggregations instead of `mean()` or `sum()` depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting it as an answer and up voting it. Thanks.